# Select with join Account and User table

Tags: soql

first time I have needed to do a join in soql and I'm lost.

in MySQL it would be

```
Select  AccountId,  Account.ParentId,  Account.Dealer_ID__c, User.Name 
FROM Account
LEFT JOIN User on (account.OwnerId = User.id)
```

but I can't make it work salesforce, the closest I have that works is:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM User 
Where Id IN (SELECT OwnerId FROM Account where Dealer_ID__c = '04932')
```

but that works only for a single id, not for getting all rows from Account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are joining on account.ownerId then

```
select name, owner.email, owner.firstname, owner.lastname from Account where ...
```

will join the Account to its owner User record

Comment: well ok, I was making it far to hard on my self. I will come back when I get a rep of 15 to upvote ;-)

Comment: no problem, while you're at it, it is worthwhile knowing about parent->child relationship queries as in `select name, (select id, name, amount from Opportunities) from Account where ...`